# PHP - Inserting date into datetime field

Tags: php

I have used a datetime field in my database for storing dates, whats the proper way to insert say todays date into that field using PHP?

Cheers,

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Do you want to know for an arbitrary date? Because for *today* I would use MySQL's `NOW()` function (assuming you use MySQL, I'm pretty sure other DBMS' offer the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can use the php [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

Answer (score 3):

Don't use PHP at all, but the database's built-in function for that.

Assuming you're using mySQL, the function's name is [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now).

[11.7. Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) in the mySQL manual

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table (`date`)VALUES (NOW());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP function [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) instead and store the value as a normal integer - that gives you much more possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else has said, using the MySQL function `NOW()` would probably be the best bet for a DATETIME column. MySQL also has many [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) available.

Personally, I do what Ivarska suggested and use an INT data type with PHP's `time()` or MySQL's `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. It gives the date in the GMT standard and it will port over easily.